# How can I add a new page by clicking to link or button in r shiny app?

Tags: r

I want to add a new page to my R shiny application.

For instance, when clicking to button or a tag I want a new page to be opened. I have written a sample application which has both a ui and a server part where I read the csv file and can do some calculations according to that data(columns and rows).

[image]

Currently the working process of the app is that when you upload the csv file and enter the **ID**, it shows the row according to that id from csv file and there are some calculations using that data.

This process is for the bank side. I would like to add a Client side to my app, for this reason I want to add something (tab or button or tag) so that when clicking it I want a new page to be opened (I mean anempty page) and in this empty page I just want to add the same code but with password as well.

When the csv file is uploaded, the customer will enter his ID as well as his **password**. The working principle will be the same but in client side(in new page) the customer will additionally add his/her password.

Is it actually possible in R shiny?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible in R shiny. [See here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/password-on-a-shiny-app/27544) for some examples/discussions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the thing that I want to do is I want to add a link(or button) to that page so that by clicking that button a new page will be be opened.And in that new page I want to have write ui and server part.